# Data getting indexed into elastic search using camel but can't be seen in Kibana or localhost:9200

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel, kibana

I'm trying to insert some data against some id into elastic search using Apache camel. I have inserted the dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm using a JSONObject as follows:

```
{
"indexId" : "someId",
"messages" : {"message1" : "data1", "message2":"data2"}

}
```

And the data is being inserted using :

```
<to id="elastic_search_camel"
                uri="elasticsearch://local?operation=INDEX&amp;indexName=messages&amp;indexType=message" />
```

I'm also able to print the data back on the console by using operation=GET_BY_ID. But I'm unable to see the index/data in Kibana or localhost:9200.

Can someone help me regarding this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you configured kibana to connect to the elastic instance?

Comment: Where are to trying to look for the data in kibana? Is there any error reported in kibana? Please add details to get the picture of the problem you are facing.

Comment: @NishantSaini I checked the config/kibana.yml. It does point to 9200 by default right? Or do we need to make any changes in the yml file?

Comment: @NishantSaini I cannot see any indices under kibana. No errors in kibana.

Comment: My problem is data not being visualized anywhere. No errors/warning while indexing or getting data back using indexId from code.

Comment: Kibana should point to the elastic instance. If the elastic instance is running on 9200 and there is an entry for it in kibana then it is fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189056/discussion-between-nishant-saini-and-rakhi-oza).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using apache Camel to connect to the ElasticSearch server. Camel creates its own elasticsearch cluster so it wasnt connecting to my cureently running server. To stop this particular behavior, you need to explicitly specify the IP and port while creating the uri:

```
<to id="elastic_search_camel"
                uri="elasticsearch://<clusterName>?operation=INDEX&amp;indexName=messages&amp;indexType=doc&amp;ip=x.x.x.x&amp;port=9300" />
```

Note : The argument transportAddresses can also be used for specifying a list of ip:port format. Check out http://camel.apache.org/elasticsearch.html for details on the same.

Specify the same in the config/elasticsearch.yml file:

```
http.port: 9200
network.host: x.x.x.x
cluster.name: <clusterName>
network.bind_host: 0
```

Dependencies in maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In option to elastic search, elasticsearch-rest can also be used. 
Where route can be specified as :

```
<to id="elastic_search_camel"
            uri="elasticsearch-rest://<clusterName>?operation=INDEX&amp;indexName=messages&amp;indexType=doc&amp;hostAddresses=x.x.x.x:9200" />
```

Documentation available on : [Elastic Search Rest](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-elasticsearch-rest/src/main/docs/elasticsearch-rest-component.adoc)

```
Maven dependencies : 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-elasticsearch-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-elasticsearch-rest-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check that the index exist - you can run

> GET es-url:9200/_cat/indices/messages*

and make sure the index exists. if the index doesn't exist then there is an issue with the indexing - either you need to create the index in advance or looks for exceptions on why it failed, both in elasticsearch and in the camel producer.

After you make sure the data is indexed in ES as expected, you can go into kibana-> settings -> index-patterns and add an index-pattern for these new indices pattern. after that you will be able to see the data in kibana

Comment: The data is getting inserted and retrieved through Java code successfully. I'm even getting the alphanumeric indexId that is returned after the successful index request. But I But I'm unable to see it on localhost:9200 or Kibana UI.

Comment: So either the cluster is configured to a port other than 9200, or not reachable through local address. I suggest that you should make sure that running curl requests to the cluster and get the data is working, before trying to make kibana work

Comment: It seems that Apache camel has its own in memory elastic search server hence we are not able to see it on loaclhost:9200.